Matching a Variable to multiple fields in Access Table
I have an Access Config table with multiple lines of possible options (see below example of table)



Type
Description




Position
Agent I


Position
Agent II


Position
Agent III



My database pulls in employee data and houses it in a table as well as has a linked table to our internal employee management system.
In my function I pull in the two record sets to see that the fields match.
I'd like to determine if the position is one of the positions in the config table to see if I even need to check the rest of the information. If the position is not one of the ones listed in the config - then I move on.
How would I accomplish this?

Perhaps with the DCount() function that returns the number of records found matching the criteria? Not very clear what you're asking.
Public Function IsFound(ByVal stringType As String, ByVal stringValue As String) As Boolean
    IsFound = DCount("*","Config","[Type]='" & stringType & "' AND [Description]='" & stringValue & "'") > 0
End Function


Then:
Dim strType As String: strType = "Position"
Dim strValue As String: strValue = "Agent I"

If IsFound(strType, strValue) Then '...

Probably you can omit the type and look only for the value, but I haven't fully understand your question.

So I was able to accomplish this by creating a separate function that pulls a subquery and returns a true false.
